# Quick sort an array and store the new ordering in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I have two int arrays *start and *end whose size might be 5 millions. *start stores the start node number of an edge and *end stores the end node number. Now I want to sort *start in ascending way and stores the new ordering scheme, like before sorting:

```
start[0] = 5
start[1] = 7
start[2] = 8
start[3] = 1
start[4] = 4
```

after sorting, it becomes

```
start[0] = 1
start[1] = 4
start[2] = 5
start[3] = 7
start[4] = 8
```

I also want to stores the new ordering scheme which is "3 4 0 1 2". The reason I want to store this new ordering scheme is that I need to use it the rearrange *end. There is a function qsort() in C library but it can only do the sorting job but doesn't store the ordering scheme. Is there any other functions which can do both? Or how to write an function on my own? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably review the data structure you're using.  If you use:

```
struct data
{
    int start;
    int end;
};
```

You can then allocate a single array of this structure, and use the standard `qsort()` function once to sort it (once).  You don't need the sort order array to order the `end` array since the start and end values are moved in parallel because they're members of the same structure:

```
int data_cmp(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{ 
    const struct data *dp1 = vp1;
    const struct data *dp2 = vp2;
    if (dp1->start < dp2->start)
        return -1;
    else if (dp1->start > dp2->start)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

And then, in some other function:

```
size_t nitems = 5000000;
struct data *array = malloc(nitems * sizeof(*array));

// ...load the array with start and end point values...

qsort(array, sizeof(array[0]), nitems, data_cmp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the way I want to implement. It's easier than what I thought before.

Comment: It's also more economical of space; you have just 10,000,000 integers stored (as 5,000,000 pairs of integers), instead of 15,000,000 with the mapping array plus the start and end arrays.

Comment: Another question is that when sorting this struct array, if start number is the same in two elements, I prefer to regard the element with smaller end number as the smaller element. So I just need to change the data_cmp function, right?

Comment: Yes, and with the unified structure, this is much simpler than with separate arrays.  Note that the framework for the `data_cmp()` function allows you to insert the two extra comparisons before the `else return 0;` part very easily — it wasn't an accident that it was written thus.

Comment: I've already solved that problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the standard `qsort()` function, as long as your `start` array is accessible to the comparison function.  The way you do it is to create the array for the new sorted order and sort *that*, based on the values of the `start` array.  The comparison function looks like:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int start_a = start[*(const size_t *)a];
    int start_b = start[*(const size_t *)b];

    return (start_a > start_b) - (start_a < start_b);
}
```

and then generating the sort order is:

```
size_t i;
size_t *sortorder = malloc(n * sizeof sortorder[0]);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sortorder[i] = i;

qsort(sortorder, n, sizeof sortorder[0], compare);
```

(where `n` is the number of elements in the `start` and `end` arrays).  This will leave `sortorder` containing the values `{ 3, 4, 0, 1, 2 }` with the example data in the question, and you can use that to create the new `start` and `end` arrays.

Comment: +1 I was going to rec an array of pointers to the original elements, but this has the benefit of not requiring the additional step `item - array_base` to reveal the original index at the cost of making the array global. If the latter is not problematic (making the array global), this is a simple algorithm and warrants serious consideration. If not, use the same algorithm but use pointers rather than indexes in the array. Nice answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, that's also a good approach.  It's essentially the same algorithm.